# counting elements in list of strings python

Tags: python-3.x

How to get number of elements in list of lists?

```
L = ['a,b,c,d','e,f,g,h,i','j,k,l',]
```

I want to find how many elements in the first list in L.

> a,b,c,d = 4 elements
>   e,f,g,h,i = 5 elements
>   j,k,l = 3 elements

Comment: That's not a list of lists, that's a list of strings. A list of lists would be `[[a,b,c,d],[e,f,g,h,i],[j,k,l]]` and would have a different answer (which would be `len(L[0])`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each string in `L` you could use [the `str.count` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) to count the number of commas and add one:

```
In [277]: L = ['a,b,c,d','e,f,g,h,i','j,k,l',]

In [278]: [item.count(',')+1 for item in L]
Out[278]: [4, 5, 3]
```